# How to style gravity form that is embedded inside email?

Tags: css, wordpress, email, inline, gravity-forms-plugin

We are using Gravity form to send out notification email when a user signs up and registers for friend/family for an event, and it's embedded with following code:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{Do you want to register any family members or friends?:30}" condition="is" value="Yes"]
You have also registered:

{list:31}

[/gravityforms]
```

Since email styling only accept inline styling, how can I style the table that is embedded inside email when I don't have direct access to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can format the email notification in the gravity form edit screen. Open your registration from for editing, go to 'Form Settings' -> 'Notifications' and at the bottom of the page check the 'Disable Auto-formating' box. Now you can write custom html into the 'Message' pane and format any way you like.

Comment: I did it already. However I can only make changes to the html but not gravity form it self. How can I have an access to it to insert inline css?

Comment: To edit the gravity form styles: in your form edit screen you can expand any of the field edit boxes, click the 'Appearance' tab and add a 'Custom CSS Class'. Then use the class in your stylesheet for style elements. In the 'Form Settings' tab you can set styles for the overall form itself.

Comment: Adding custom css class works for WP pages, but not for tables inside email, since it only takes inline styling.

Comment: What table is inside the email? How is it getting there? Is it not part of the gravity form notification?

Comment: The table that is a part of the gravity form notification, generated on the fly with [gravityforms] tag. And I'm not sure which php file is writing it.

Comment: And you're not able to use a custom html template and merge tags in the notificatins tab to generate the table yourself? My only other suggestion would be to disable the notification and use the gform_notification filter to generate and send your own confirmation. https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_notification/

Comment: My teammate located the file, answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found where the table inside gravity form is coming from: wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/includes/fields/class-gf-field-list.php - get_field_input

So one needs to go to (line 393 in my file): 
    $list = "